# Using Preparse field to display matrix blocks in Control Panel, limitations?

Tags: matrix, control-panel

I can successfully use the Preparse field type to display matrix fields in the control panel, however, the output is very limited. **Even my 
 tag is stripped out.**

Is there any way to do this short of writing a plug-in?

And if not, what is the simplest possible plug-in I could use as a base for this.

```
{% for thing in entry.myMatrixField%}
  {{ thing.item }} - {{ thing.amount|number_format(2, '.', ',') }}<br>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2):

There may be a better answer, but this is what I have come up with. Using Control Panel JS, combined with Preparse field(s), I am adding characters in like this

```
{% for thing in entry.myMatrixField %}
  {{ thing.item }} - {{ thing.amount|number_format(2, '.', ',') }}^
{% endfor %}
```

And then using some basic jQuery to replace the ^ character with a line break. It's a bit clumsy, but it works. Now I can get Matrix fields to display in the control panel. **Items**, **Budget line**, **Prices** are all fields within my Matrix block. Just have to get them out separately.
[image]